# Where are business obligations, like a property lease, on the debt seniority ladder?

Tags: investing, debt, bankruptcy

Consider the perspective of a REIT.  If one of the REITs tenants files for bankruptcy, does the REIT get paid first to satisfy the terms of the lease or do the tenant's bond holders get paid first?

I'm trying evaluate the risk of an investment portfolio that includes REITs.

Comment: That completely depends on the location.